# How to gsub slash (/) to "" in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To gsub / to "" ruby

I tried as,

```
ss = "http://url.com/?code=\#{code}"
```

I am fetching this url from database
then have to gsub \ to '' to pass the dynamic value in code

How to gsub \ to ''

required output

```
ss = "http://url.com/?code=#{code}"
```

Comment: `'/'` or `'\'`? What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you may be asking is "how do I force Ruby to evaluate string interpolation when the interpolation pattern has been escaped?" In that case, you can do this:

```
eval("\"#{ss}\"")
```

If this is what you are attempting to do, though, I would highly discourage you. You should not store strings containing the literal characters `#{ }` in your database fields. Instead, use `%s` and then [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) the values into them:

```
# Stored db value
ss = "http://url.com/?code=%s"

# Replace `%s` with value of `code` variable
result = sprintf(ss, code)
```

If you only need to know how to remove `\` from your string, though, you can represent a `\` in a String or Regexp literal by escaping it with another `\`.

```
ss.gsub(/\\/,'')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is actually not a problem. When you write `"http://url.com/?code=\#{code}"` in ruby, `\#` means that ruby is escaping the `#` character, cause `#` is a protected character. So you should have the backslash to escape it.

Just to prove this, if you write in a console your string with single quotes (single quotes will escape any special character (but single quotes, of course)):

```
>> 'http://url.com/?code=#{code}'
=> "http://url.com/?code=\#{code}"
```

This may be a little obscure but, if you want to evaluate the parameter code in the string, you could do something like this:

```
>> code = 'my_code'
>> eval("\"http://url.com/?code=\#{code}\"")
=> "http://url.com/?code=my_code"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try in this way also, working fine for my case.

```
  url = 'www.abc.com?user_id=#{user[:id]}'

  uri = URI.parse(url.gsub("=\#", "="))

  uri.query = URI.encode_www_form({user_id: 12})

  puts uri.to_s ==> "www.abc.com?user_id=12"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do byt what's wrong with just using string interpolation `"www.abc.com?user_id=#{variable}"`?

Comment: Hi @MikeSzyndel  I am storing this "www.abc.com?user_id=#{variable}" in database table for my specific case when I am fetching this as it is it replacing with "www.abc.com?user_id=\#{variable}" and not returning with 'variable'  value that is why I am doing like this